# An open source chat application in Java EE or flash?

Tags: java, flash, jakarta-ee, chat

I need a starting point to develop an on site chat to communicate site visitors with site owners.
I'm looking for an open source chat application written in Java/Java EE. 
Do you know any good applications that I could use?

I'm also not sure about the architecture of the solution. Currently I'm hesitate between:

- server side solution: a Java EE application
- client side solution: something that can talk over jabber/xmpp

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend the smack libraries and the openfire chat server, both from [Ignite Realtime](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) and free to use.

Already used them in some Java projects, openfire is easy to configure, smack is pretty easy to use. And smack offers a brilliant debugging feature which really saved me a few times!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [list](http://java-source.net/open-source/chat-servers) of chat servers. Check freecs.

Comment: I did some prototyping a while back, after that we went for a commercial solution.